# Clases y herencia PHP

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de confeccionar

Una clase `Persona` que tenga como atributos:

- nombre
- género
- edad

tengo que definir como responsabilidades:

- Un método que cargue los datos personales y otro que los imprima
- plantear una segunda clase `Empleado` que herede de la clase Persona.
- añadir un atributo sueldo, tipo de contrato y los métodos de cargar el sueldo e imprimir su sueldo.

Esta es mi conexión a la base de datos de momento

```
<?php

class Conexion {
    private $servidor ="localhost";
    private $usuario ="root";
    private $password ="";
    private $bd ="db";

    public function conexion(){
        $conexion = mysqli_connect($this->servidor,
                                   $this->usuario,
                                   $this->password,
                                   $this->bd);
        return $conexion;
    }
}
$obj = new Conexion();
    if($obj->conexion()){
        echo "Exito";
    }else {
        echo "Fallo";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Vale amigo ya edito lo que he adelnatado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

- Para declarar las 3 propiedades lo podemos hacer de este modo dentro de la clase:

Código

```
public $nombre;
public $genero;
public $edad;
```

- Ahora creamos el método que cargue los datos personales, en este punto dado que los atributos están haciendo referencia a la clase `Persona`, lo que podemos hacer es emplear al método mágico `__construct()` que se ejecutará inmediatamente la clase sea instanciada.

Así:

```
public function __construct($nombre, $genero, $edad)
{
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
    $this->genero = $genero;
    $this->edad   = $edad;
}
```

- Ahora poder imprimir dichos atributos de la clase creamos un método de este modo el cual solo los retorna en una *string* con formato personalizado

De este modo:

```
public function imprimeDatos()
{
    return "Mi nombre es: {$this->nombre}, mi género es {$this->genero} y mi edad es: {$this->edad}";
}
```

Ahora creamos la clase hija, `Empleado` que será la que herede de la principal `Persona` los métodos y atributos.

- El constructor de la clase hija recibe los parámetros de la clase padre, mas los parámetros de la propia clase, es decir aquellos que son solo atributos de la clase empleado:
- Por dentro recibimos un llamado al método constructor de la clase padre que inicializará las propiedades de la clase `Persona`

Así:

```
 public function __construct($nombre, $genero, $edad, $sueldo, $tipoContrato)
    {
        parent::__construct($nombre, $genero, $edad);
        $this->sueldo = $sueldo;
        $this->tipoContrato = $tipoContrato;
    }
```

- Ahora creamos los 2 métodos propios de la clase `Empleado` uno para indicar el sueldo y otro para indicar el tipo de contrato:

Así:

```
public function cargaSueldo()
{
    return "Tu sueldo ahora será de: $".$this->sueldo = $this->sueldo + 20;
}

public function tipoContrato()
{
    return "Tu tipo de contrato es: {$this->tipoContrato}";
}
```

Finalmente creamos la instancia de la clase hija referida a un objeto llamado `empleadoRoberto`, le pasamos los valores requerido y accedemos a cada método existente tanto en la clase hija como en la clase padre:

```
$empleadoRoberto = new Empleado("Roberto", "Masculino", 23, 3500, "de por vida");
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->imprimeDatos();
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->cargaSueldo();
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->tipoContrato();
```

Finalmente tu código se vería así:

```
<?php

class Persona
{
    public $nombre;
    public $genero;
    public $edad;

    public function __construct($nombre, $genero, $edad)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->genero = $genero;
        $this->edad   = $edad;
    }

    public function imprimeDatos()
    {
        return "Mi nombre es: {$this->nombre}, mi género es {$this->genero} y mi edad es: {$this->edad}";
    }

}

class Empleado extends Persona
{
    public function __construct($nombre, $genero, $edad, $sueldo, $tipoContrato)
    {
        parent::__construct($nombre, $genero, $edad);
        $this->sueldo = $sueldo;
        $this->tipoContrato = $tipoContrato;
    }

    public function cargaSueldo()
    {
        return "Tu sueldo ahora será de: $".$this->sueldo = $this->sueldo + 20;
    }

    public function tipoContrato()
    {
        return "Tu tipo de contrato es: {$this->tipoContrato}";
    }
}

$empleadoRoberto = new Empleado("Roberto", "Masculino", 23, 3500, "de por vida");
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->imprimeDatos();
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->cargaSueldo();
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->tipoContrato();
```

Dando en pantalla algo como esto:

```
Mi nombre es: Roberto, mi género es Masculino y mi edad es: 23
Tu sueldo ahora será de: $3520
Tu tipo de contrato es: de por vida
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero "**clase persona**"

```
Class Persona {
    protected $nombre;
    protected $genero;
    protected $edad;

    public function establecerDatos($nombre, $genero, $edad){
      $this->nombre = $nombre;
      $this->genero = $genero;
      $this->edad = $edad;
    }

    public function imprimirDatos(){
      echo $this->nombre . ' ' . $this->edad . ' ' . $this->genero;
    }
}
```

*ahora puedes crear un empleado*

```
Class Empleado extends Persona {
  protected $sueldo;
  protected $tipoContrato;

  public function establecerSueldo($sueldo){
     $this->sueldo = $sueldo; 
  }

  public function obtenerSueldo(){
     echo $this->sueldo;
  }
}
```

Ya tenemos las clases ahora a **crear una instancia**

```
$miPersona = new Persona()
$miPersona->establecerDatos('StackOverflow', 'Otro', 10);
$miPersona->imprimirDatos();
```

Ahora si quieres un empleado

```
$miEmpleado = new Empleado()

#Puedes llenar datos igual que en persona por que lo hereda
$miEmpleado->establecerDatos('PHP Max', 'Otro', 99); 
$miEmpleado->establecerSueldo('$5000');
$miEmpleado->ImprimirDatos();
$miEmpleado->obtenerSueldo();
```

Para jugar puedes hacer

```
$miPersona->establecerSueldo('$2000');
```

Esto te dará un error por que solo el empleado tiene el método de establecer sueldo.